# Is it possible to run the node-webkit from the console without having GUi

Tags: linux, node.js, shell

I want to take a [lightweight linux](http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/downloads.html) (10 mb) and add to it nw.js (20 mb) that would raise it to the raspberry pi and run index.html application.
Can I do it without the GUI (GNOME, KDE)?
if i can, how?
else which GUI with minimum weight should I use?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot run Node-webkit (or nw.js as it is called now) without a GUI desktop environment.

- If you just want to build a CLI application that, try using regular Node without nw.js
- If you want to execute DOM operations within your application, you could check out [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)
- If you want to create a graphical user interface in a CLI environment, there is [Blessed](https://github.com/chjj/blessed) which I haven't worked with myself yet  but it seems pretty powerful.

If this does not answer your question, please try rephrasing your question and perhaps adding some more explanation of what you want to achieve.

*Edit in response to clarification of the question*

Currently this is not possible, because showing index.html would require a webbrowser, which requires a GUI desktop. The best solution is to find a lightweight linux distro with a simple desktop GUI, install your nw.js app on the system, and set up the system to automatically launch the app on boot. You can disable desktop toolbars and remove any icons from the desktop to make it look like there is no desktop at all, but right now there still has to be a desktop GUI running in the background, to support the webbrowser application.

There is a project called [Node-OS](https://node-os.com/) that seems to promise to do exactly what you need. I myself have been following it for a while, since I've had the same idea as you, but it is not ready yet and it seems it will stay that way for a while. But it is an interesting project to follow if you're going in that direction.

Comment: i rephrasing my question